# Integral of Fourier series and its partial sum

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

How can I show that for a Fourier series u(x) and it's associated partial sum 
$u_J(x)=\sum\limits_{k=-J}^J u_ke^{2\pi i kx}\,dx$

that $\int_0^1u(x)u_J(x)\,dx = \sum\limits_{k=-J}^J |u_J|^2$

I have proved the result when integrating $|u_J(x)|^2$ but cannot do this one.

Comment: Just directly substitute in $u_J(x)$ into the integral, take the sum out by linearity and see that you've got your integral evaluating to your fourier coefficient in each term, and you have it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $u(x)$ is real:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 u(x) u_J(x)\ dx &= \int_0^1 u(x) \sum_{k=-J}^{J}u_k e^{2\pi i k x}\ dx \\
&= \sum_{k=-J}^J u_k \int_0^1 u(x) e^{2\pi i k x}\ dx \\
&= \sum_{k=-J}^J u_k \overline{\int_0^1 \overline{u(x)} e^{-2\pi i k x}\ dx} \\
&= \sum_{k=-J}^J u_k \overline{\int_0^1 u(x) e^{-2\pi i k x}\ dx} \\
&= \sum_{k=-J}^J u_k \overline{u_k} \\
&= \sum_{k=-J}^J |u_k|^2
\end{aligned}$$